# Android Studio - How to let user build a dictionary

Tags: java, android, android-studio, input

I'm building an app, where the user adds words to the app itself and then can access them. Think a basic dictionary without the ' = ' part. Just a list of words.
As such, i have one EditText and a button to 'add'. Now how would one go about saving that one word into something, that could later be used in a listView? Moreover, how would one save out that input *permanently* into the app, not just for the current running instance of the app, but actually save it out?
I was thinking of using arrayList or even a map - for the dictionary purposes later, but have no idea where to save it, how to save it, how to then access it...

My (uneducated) thought process was something like creating a text file in the values dictionary, that will have a map in it. then every time the user adds a new word, it would read the map into memory, add the word to it, and save it out anew. But I would think this would be very irresponsible management of resources, having to read it all into memory if only one thing gets added. So something like 'add to the last line of a file' would probably be better and then read the file as a whole only when accessing the listView? Then again, maybe my whole thought process here is flawed, but thats what im here for :)

So what would you java-savvy people think?

Any and all help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you do a Google search on this? There have to be leads of tutorials for this exact thing ...

Comment: I did, yes, tried my best, wouldn't post otherwise. Posting here really as a last resort...
Also, so many downvotes from people who don't even comment why? I thought this site was better than that... Apparently I am proven very wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright. since no one had the 30 seconds to spend to just type
'hey man, look into SQLite database and recyclerView, that would solve all your needs i reckon. you can find even a good bit of good tutorials on youtube on the subject. it may seem daunting at first, but will reward you with good practices and get you what you need.',
but still so many had time to just click the down arrow hence less people bothering to see my question (thank you, much appreciated, really...), let me answer my own question after days of researching and finding more sources than one to not base my decisions on one found thread, should anyone stumble on the same problem and find this.

I ended up using an SQLite database to store all the input data by the user, eventually added import/export for the database for when the app is uninstalled to not loose all the data already there as well (which, if you're exporting into the phone or generally copying outside of the app folder (which is the only way to prevent created data deletion on app uninstall from what i understand), you require permissions that you need to prompt the user for, not just insert a few lines in the manifest like 99% of threads suggest, but thats a whole other topic, just good to mention i thought), and using recyclerView to make better use of resources when the db gets larger.
The most challenging was trying to understand what i was doing, haha, but coming from a programming background, eventually, it became easier. Whoever is going for a similar thing, i would suggest to look into the same ideas when researching before your project.

Ended up introducing an OnClick on each of the recyclerView items and getting the clicked item's details and working with them. also something i've found very little documentation on.

People here very easily forget that this is a site for helping people, not another youtube, where people just press dislike on whatever and move on, or throw in a mean comment. Thus, lets keep it different over here and be mature about these things please.
Hope this helps someone :)